# 404 error with POST request using express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am running this function that should post data to my express server. The function is called when a button is clicked.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/test', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'hello world'
      }),
    })

    // const data = await response.json()
    const data = await response
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Here is my express configuration

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/api/test', (req: any, res: any) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json({ status: 'ok' })
})

app.listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Server started on 1337')
})
```

The problem is that when I click the button I receive a 404 error for the POST request and  my `console.log(response)` results in the following.

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:1337/api/test", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
​
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 404
​
statusText: "Not Found"
​
type: "cors"
​
url: "http://localhost:1337/api/test"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing a POST request from the client end but do not have a POST request handler configured on the server-side. You instead have a GET request handler. The solution is to either add a handler for POST request or turn your POST request method to GET.

Answer (score 1):

> In the backend change app.get to app.post

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

// here
app.post('/api/test', (req: any, res: any) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json({ status: 'ok' })
})

app.listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Server started on 1337')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

in the server you have not implemented POST endpoint, You have implemented GET endpoint only

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning response from the fetchData function.
You should simply return the response as below.
-Also there is no post request handler at server side.
You can add post request handler as you have written for get request.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'hello world'
  }),
})

// const data = await response.json()
const data = await response
//need to return response as below
 return data.json();
```

}